# OpenGL ES texture mapping

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, uv-mapping

I need to draw circles in my Android application. Actually it is a Pacman game and I need to draw tablets. Since there are many tablets on field I decided to draw each tablet with a single polygon.

Here is the illustration of my idea:

http://www.advancedigital.ru/ideal_circle_with_only_one_polygon.jpg

Vertex coordrs:

```
//  (x, y)
0 : -R, R * (Math.sqrt(2) + 1)
1 : -R, -R
2 : R * (Math.sqrt(2) + 1), -R
```

Vertex coords are calculated relative to circle center to place circles with ease later.

The problem is in texture mapping, according to my calculations UVs should be like this

```
0 : 0, -(Math.sqrt(2) + 0.5)
1 : 0, 1
2 : 1, (Math.sqrt(2) + 0.5)
```

But negative V value causes application to show only black screen. That is why I think that I'm missing something or I'm going the wrong way…

My question is: Is it possible to render the texture in that way or not? If it isn't possible, what is the best way to draw small dots?

P.S: I'm working with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android.

Seems to me, that this guy is trying to do [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397170/opengl-es-texture-mapping-overflow).

Comment: Have you tried setting the `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/T` texture parameters to `GL_CLAMP` or `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` ?

Comment: No I had not tried before your advice, but it did the trick! Please write the answer to the question I will accept it. The idea is to use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, instead of GL_REPEAT. Note that GL_CLAMP seems to be unavailable in OpenGL ES 2.0 or it spells somewhat different.

Comment: I also have an error in UV coords - the UV pair for the 2 point is: 1, (Math.sqrt(2) + **1.5**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` texture parameters are set to `GL_REPEAT` by default. Set them to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead to get the effect you're looking for (see the [glTexParameter documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml))